# Rendering a Number to the View using String Interpolation in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am querying our mongoDB API endpoint in order to obtain the value that represents the total number of records. If I try that API endpoint call directly in Postman, I get the number "1227" returned (a number, not a string). Now I am trying to get that value rendered to the view in my Angular app. I am using an observable to get the value. In my service I have this:

```
getStaffCount() {
    return this._http.get(`https://api.somesite.com/v0/staff/count?apikey=someapikey`)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch(this._errorsCountHandler);
}
```

Then, in my component I am subscribing and saving the result of this observable in a variable like this:

```
      const counts = this.staffService.getStaffCount()
          .subscribe(resRecordsData => this.records = resRecordsData,
          responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
```

Then, in my view I am using string interpolation, like this:

```
{{counts}}
```

This produces the following error:

> EXCEPTION: Error trying to diff '1227'

How can I resolve this error? Is this a matter of needing to convert the number to a string before rendering to the screen? Or is there something else I can do to handle it? Perhaps Angular has a way I can structure the value so that it's evaluated and rendered on the fly in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `counts` is a `Subscription` object, not a `number`, which is what `subscribe()` returns.

The result from the API (via the observable) is stored right now in `this.records`, which is what you should put into the string interpolation in your template.

If that doesn't work, you'll need to inspect `resRecordsData` in your browser's debugger and see how exactly the JSON result is formatted.

Comment: Thanks, John. You're right. The key was in using {{records}} in the view.